# How can I add multiple images for each Q in javascript?

Tags: javascript, image, slickquiz

It is too difficult for me to add images in this format, with every try, I got error's, im out of my ideas how to keep it working.
I wannt to add images in the questions. Each question with each image :S.
If anybody can help me out. thanks :S

```
var questions = [
{
    label : 'What is the capital of Norway IMG HERE?',
    options : ['Stockholm', 'Oslo', 'Copenhagen'],
    answer : ['Oslo'],
    forceAnswer : true
},
{
    label : 'Who was the champion of this years soccer world cup in South Africa IMG HERE?',
    options : ['Brazil', 'Netherlands', 'Spain'],
    answer : ['Spain']
},
{
    label : 'Who was the prime minister(s) of England during World War II IMG HERE?',
    options : ['Clement Attlee', 'Sir Winston Churchill', 'Neville Chamberlain', 'Sir Anthony Eden'],
    answer : [1,2] // refers to the second and third option
},
```

Comment: You need to add your "tries" to your question so we can help you with the code you've written.

Comment: :S i need ideas, im searching for javascript articles too but everything i try will not work.